How to insert data in User table through own portlet liferay 7.4
How to insert data in User table through own portlet
How to insert data in user_ table in liferay 7.4 though own portlet
I have created a custom entity in service.xml and perform the add operation .data is inserted in custum userdefined table in service.xml.but requirement is that the user details is also inserted in User_ table of liferay.

Do not think in terms of database entries: This is a recipe for disaster: User records need entries in other tables as well, and the only approved way to make sure everything exists is to use the API.
Luckily, UserLocalService.addUserWithWorkflow(...) does what you want to do.

Thanks Olaf . I am new in liferay can you share the some resource where i am get some code base for the same that helps me a lot.

You can just search for use of the method that I provided. However, this smells like an x-y problem to me, and there might be better solutions (like LDAP-import, Single-Sign-On, or others) for your problem than manually creating user accounts.
